# Rigid Body - Constant Speed

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm trying to render an animation with motion blur, and I want the motion blur to start since frame 0.

To achieve this, I need the Rigid Body to start simulating before frame 0.
How can I achieve this?

Here is a video reference, showing how it's performing right now.
https://youtube.com/shorts/i7vPjfqD92o?feature=share

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the start and end frames of the Rigid Body simulations in the *Properties Editor ► Scene tab ► Rigid Body World panel ► Cache sub-panel*:

[image]

That being said, even if you set it to zero, it doesn't seem like it is able to bake the frame zero, or any negative frame for that matter.

> The simulation is only calculated for positive frames in between the Start and End frames of the Cache panel, whether you bake or not. So if you want a simulation that is longer than the default frame range you have to change the End frame.
>
> Source: **[Baking Physics Simulations — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/physics/baking.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.0#options)**

So perhaps the best solution is to offset your whole animation instead.

Alternatively, you can do your rigid body simulation, bake it into keyframes with the menu *Object ► Rigid Body ► Bake to Keyframes*, and then add your own keyframe at frame zero to add the missing movement.

Comment: I set it to -10, and still doesn't gives me that effect to frame 0. I'm worried about offsetting because I need to match the animation frames to After Effects, which have the same frame count. Isn't there a more practical/organized way?

Comment: Please see my edit bellow quote